How to change UPDATE AUTHORITY for SPL-TOKEN using solana cli
I minted my spl-token a few days in Solana mainnet using solana cli.

But as you can see, update-authority is NULL.
How can I set update-authority by my address?
I have tried some solana-cli commands for this feature but failed.
I use ledger hardware wallet.
If possible, can we use solana-cli to set update-authority?

The updateAuthority is used by Metaplex Token Metadata program to mark whether you can update the token's metadata in the future.
Once revoked, there isn't a way to undo this.
ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update

So I can't change my update-authority for SPL-token, right?

if the token metadata is mutable and your address is the updateAuthority, you can. Once it's null you can't. This also applies to the mintAuthority and FreezeAuthority

currently, I can update mintAuthority and FresszeAuthority even though updateAuthority is null. And updateAuthority is N/A now. What doesn it mean?
